# interpolation in class names

Tags: angularjs, pug

I am using angularjs and jade to write the html

I want to write a class name as col-md-{{12/columns}} in jade

```
.col-md-{{12/columns}}.small-padding
```

this is converted into

```
<div class="col-md-">{{12/columns}}.small-padding</div>
```

How to specify the class name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.small-padding(class="col-md-{{12/columns}}")
```

Comment: Care to add an explanation of why this worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but probably you have to change startSymbol and endSymbol in $interpolationProvider coz they are used by Jade too.

```
var customInterpolationApp = angular.module('customInterpolationApp', []);

customInterpolationApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});
```

[DOCS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/%24interpolateProvider).